# Treemap with 3 Strings arguments java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, treemap

I need to save 3 variables in any structure data in java, I was think in treemap because a I need sort the map alphabetically, but, the treemap only take 2 arguments.

Any other structure when a can sort the structure in funtion of first argument? like

```
["abc","house","car"]
["bdc","house2","car2"]
```

Comment: You can create a separate class which has 3 fields to represent these 3 values in a row, then you create a new object of that class for each row by setting these values and adding them to a `List`. Later, you can sort `Collections.sort(list, firstFieldComparator)` them using a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of arrays with a custom comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new String[]{"bdc", "house2", "car2"});
    data.add(new String[]{"abc", "house", "car"});

    printData(data);

    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        }
    });

    System.out.println();
    printData(data);

}

public static void printData(List<String[]> data){
    for(String[] s: data){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}
```

Output:
Before sorting:
[bdc, house2, car2]
[abc, house, car]

After sorting:
[abc, house, car]
[bdc, house2, car2]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with these 3 fields

```
     class Person 
   {
     String name;
     String houseName;
     String carName;
    // add getter... setter..
     ......  
   }
```

Now you can sort it using name or any other field.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new Person(name1, housname1, carname1));
data.add(new Person(name2, housename2, carname2));

// sorting using name 
data.sort((o1, o2)->o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));

// print data
printData(data);
```

}

```
public static void printData(List<Person> data)
{
   data.forEach(obj -> System.out.println("name" + obj.getName() + " " + "home" + obj.getHomeName() + " " + "car" + obj.getCarName()));
```

}